# Comparison between weighted and unweighted surveys

Tags: survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

I was hoping to get your take on comparing the results of a weighted survey with an unweighted survey.

I have the results of two different surveys conducted in my state.

Survey A was a multi-stage, stratified, population-weighted survey which included approximately 11,000 respondents. The data set includes the primary sampling unit, sampling strata, and weights.

Survey B was a large survey conducted by a state agency which was meant to include all relevant members of the state (in actuality, it includes approximately 70%). This data set includes approximately 1.8 million responses. There are no PSUs, strata, or weights and I can’t find detailed documentation on the sampling/data cleaning procedures.

There are 6 yes/no questions that are identically worded across surveys and we would like to compare the percentage of respondents endorsing each item. Right now, my best idea is to compute the difference in percentages and use the standard errors to compute the standard error for the difference.

I was wondering:

1. Is there a better way to conduct this comparison given the potential differences in the sampling designs, and
2. We suspect some of the apparent differences we see are due to demographic confounding between surveys. Can you recommend a method to conduct an adjusted comparison? Right now, my idea is to stratify based on the demographic categories and conduct the same analysis described above.

Thanks in advance!